# Angular 2 Promise passing

Tags: angular, angular-promise, es6-promise

I am a little confused on why I can't access the values in this promise.

I have a service with a method that returns a promise as follows:

```
import { MainContent } from './../../shared/mainContent.model';
import { LargeIconCard } from './../../shared/largeIconCard.model';
import { LocoGpsData } from './../../shared/locoGpsData.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MainContentService {

  constructor() { }
  simplePromiseExample(): Promise<MainContent> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const mainContent = new MainContent();
      mainContent.test = 'test';
      resolve(mainContent);
    });
  }

}
```

The MainContent object looks like this:

```
import { LargeIconCard } from './largeIconCard.model';
export class MainContent {
    public largeIconCardList: LargeIconCard[] = new Array();
    public test: string;
    constructor() {}
}
```

In my app component, I'm calling the service, returning the promise, and setting it to 'mainContentTest'

```
import { MainContent } from './shared/mainContent.model';
import { MainContentService } from './services/main-content/main-content.service';
import { LocoGpsData } from './shared/locoGpsData.model';
import { HeaderUserInput } from './shared/headerUserInput.model';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LocoGpsService } from './services/loco-gps/loco-gps.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  mainContentTest: Promise<MainContent>;

  constructor(
    private locoGpsService: LocoGpsService,
    private mainContentService: MainContentService) {}

  onSearchDataset(userInput: HeaderUserInput) {
      this.mainContentTest = this.mainContentService.simplePromiseExample();
  }
}
```

In my app.component.html if I do the following, I am seeing the data:

```
{{ mainContentTest | async | json }}

"{ "largeIconCardList": [], "test": "test" }"
```

My question is how do i get access to this `test` value? If I try something like

```
{{ mainContentTest.test }}
```

I get:

> cannot read property 'test' of undefinded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `{{ (mainContentTest | async).test }}` rather than just `{{ mainContentTest.test }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ (mainContentTest | async)?.test }}
```